sealing huge air gap in basement from crawlspace
I've got a huge hole in my basement wall that lets in cold air from the connected crawlspace. I've read that cutting airflow into the basement is one of the best actions I can take for insulating my house.
I've been thinking of a solution like cutting a piece of plywood that fits snugly into the hole and putting batt insulation on one side of it; seems like cutting the wood to fit the hole snugly would be a challenge? An alternative I've thought of is to put hinges onto the wood piece above the hole and let the plywood sit "rest above" the hole (i.e., on this side of the basement wall).
Any other advice about insulating the basement / crawlspace would be greatly appreciated - I'm in a 100 year old house that stays cold in winter.


Revise to add details about your "hole", please. Also tell us what the wall's made of. (At this point I can only assume rough mortared stone.) A photo would be very helpful in showing context. Good solutions depend on better information. Also note that your crawl space probably needs alternative ventilation to the exterior to remain not gross, unless you're in a very dry climate. Do you have that in place? Please see [ask] and take the [tour].

Unless you need to retain access through that hole, why not simply brick it up and seal the pipe penetration with expanding foam?  If you do need to retain access, frame out and build an insulated access door (still seal the pipe penetration).
You may benefit from some insulation inside the basement too, but that is a separate issue.

It will also make the insulation above the opening useful.

Pictures would be a huge help to us to offer better solutions than guesswork.  If it's a rough opening and big enough, I'd suggest framing it out with something like 2x2 to give a regualar-shaped opening, then attach a piece of plywood (with insulation behind it) to that opening with screws so you could remove it in the future if needed.

Assuming that is your access to the crawl space, you need to put in a door.  Here is one approach:

Straighten out the bottom, and the area around the pipe, with cement.  Doesn't have to be perfect, just a lot better.  The sides and top are good enough.
Frame it with 1x6 screwed/glued all around the sides of the hole.  Fill gaps with spray foam, or if there are no large gaps, just caulk.  The frame should be nicely rectangular and as much as possible the front should be flat, square, and flush with the wall.
Build a door as you described.  Hinged at the top, fitting over the hole not in it, with solid foam insulation on the back cut to fit tightly in your frame. You can add a rubber gasket around the edges if you want.  If your frame face and plywood are both dead flat you shouldn't need it.
Put a latch on the bottom and another one to hold it open securely, so it won't fall on your head.

Later you can add a permanent step below it and an LED work light inside.
